# Cannot change brightness on my laptop (Lenovo ThinkPad Edge E535)

Tags: 12.10, brightness, lenovo

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my laptop but I am frustrated by not being able to increase or decrease the screen brightness by using neither the keyboard controls nor the brightness slider in the "Brightness & Lock" settings. It is weird because I was able to do it on Ubuntu 12.04 but not 12.10. Any help??

Answer (score 1):

I have the keys working. I had to download the latest drivers (testing not stable) from the AMD website. I found the problem in the Catalyst center when I didn't see the discrete graphics card.

I installed using the `--buildpkg` switch when I ran the drivers. The problem isn't the screen it is the video card driver.