# Screen turns black when lowering brightness

Tags: screen, brightness, xrandr

I have recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my Lenovo Thinkpad Edge E535 laptop along with Jupiter for power saving.

And every time I use Fn key to alter the brightness, the screen turns blank and then turns off. It comes back after pressing a key or about 6 seconds.

Turning inactive is set to never, dimming to save power is unchecked, ran xset s off as well...

From time to time, the screen goes blank even without pressing anything. It happens even when Jupiter is not running.

Does anybody have an idea what might be causing it?

I forgot to say that with Ubuntu 13.04, this didn't happen, but the screen sometimes seemed to be blinking though.

This is the output:

```
xrandr --current
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 1600 x 1600
LVDS connected 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1366x768       60.0*+   50.0  
   1360x768       60.0     50.0  
   1280x768       60.0     50.0  
   1280x720       60.0     50.0  
   1024x768       60.0     50.0  
   1024x600       60.0     50.0  
   800x600        60.0     50.0  
   800x480        60.0     50.0  
   640x480        60.0     50.0  
DFP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
CRT1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

New output

rockstone@rockstonepc:~$ lspci | grep VGA
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Device 9903
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Thames XT/GL [Radeon HD 7600M Series]

Answer (score 1):

most probably, the brightness settings of your notebook is a bit out of standard, similar to apple notebooks. You can play with brightness settings trough xrandr to get more detailed message what is going on. Most probably it is a hardware specific. Type:

```
xrandr --current
```

add the output to your question. This will return to you the notebook display ID, could be LVDS0 or LVDS-0

```
xrandr --output <outputname> --brightness 0.8
```

- try different values. Setup the monitor cloning in case you get into blank screen, so you will see the screen on external display (if you have some).
- try to search for help for your hardware or report a bug. Brightness keys probably are not implemented good for your notebook type.

Added: Definitely there is a solution for that: ([Cannot change brightness on my laptop (Lenovo ThinkPad Edge E535)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/245213/cannot-change-brightness-on-my-laptop-lenovo-thinkpad-edge-e535)) but it is for 12.10

Comment: I just managed to plug in an external monitor... altering brightness makes it go blank as well.

Comment: L- @RockStone: this is weird, because if you modify brightness with xrandr, you surely make changes for specific hardware output.

Comment: I meant altering with Fn keys... using xrandr works fine. But still there's the thing with the screen going blank without any reason, not pressing anything.

Comment: L- @RockStone .. allright. Then there are some values preconfigured when you add or reduce brightnes by keyboard. This goes with profile of your graphics card. Try to install additional drivers or remove them completely. Add result of `lspci | grep VGA` to your question.

Comment: Added... Installing drivers was interesting, at first I wasn't able to make ATI 7670 operational... and now I can't remember if the problem started after installing it at last. BTW, tried xrandr --output LVDS --set BACKLIGHT combination
the screen doesn't go blank only at some levels. Otherwise still the same so it might be cause by some weird value assigned to the keys

Comment: L- @Rockstone: this definitely looks like Macbook problems. And they usually solve it by different GC driver. For example each even value was blank, each odd value was ok. I had similar troubles with my DELL, where brightness was "jumping" up and down. Driver shoud have set the profile / values properly to your hardware. Try to install additional drivers to ATI Radeon from the repository. If you just use them, remove them completely and try different one. ...And, you can install Catalyst drivers from the deb package, downloadable from ATI.

Comment: So... I've tried to install driver from ATI, it succeeded, but after reboot nothing works fine... when pressing Fn key for brightness, the indicator changes, but the screen stays still. Launcher is quite big (default size), AMD CCC cannot be opened, saying there's no driver... And attempts to install drivers from Additional drivers fails, each one of them... Now what? :-D

Comment: I think I'm done with Ubuntu... I had to reinstall it for 4 times in a month... It's like a card house.

Comment: Ok, It doesn't even boot properly now, screaming with errors and problems... downloaded Fedora already... anyway, thanks for your effort